# VBA Index Match

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an Index/Match lookup formula which I would like to incorporate in an ActiveX Form. The code is

```
=IF(A2="","No Search Criteria",IFERROR(INDEX(AssetList,MATCH(A2,AssetList[Asset '#],0),1),INDEX(AssetList,MATCH(A2,AssetList[Serial '#],0),1))
```

)
This allows me to search for an Asset Number or Serial Number of an item and return its Asset Number. The cells next to the one containing this code have modified versions to return its Serial Number, Item Number, and Ratchet Size. I'm trying to create a form which will perform these same functions, allowing the user to type in an Asset or Serial Number into SearchCriteriaTextBox and return the appropriate values to AssetNumberListBox, SerialNumberListBox, ItemNumberListBox, and RatchetSizeListBox when SearchButton is clicked.

So far I've got:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()        
AssetNumberListBox.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SearchCriteriaTextBox.Value, Sheet2.ListObjects("AssetList").ListColumns("Asset#").DataBodyRange, False)
SerialNumberListBox.Value =
ItemNumberListBox.Value =
RatchetSizeListBox.Value =


End Sub
```

But this gives me "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" when I click SearchButton. I'm pretty new to Excel and especially VBA, so if anybody has any ideas to at least get one of the ListBoxes to populate so I can adapt the code to the others I'd appreciate it. For reference, I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows 7. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

so basically, I understood that the table structure of your data is as follows :

```
Asset Number | Serial Number | Item Number | Rachet Size
```

First point is looking up the data :

Why are you using `MATCH` function that returns the position ?:

```
AssetNumberListBox.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SearchCriteriaTextBox.Value, Sheet2.ListObjects("AssetList").ListColumns("Asset#").DataBodyRange, False)
```

You should instead use the `WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP` to return the value.

Then, in the second point, in order to populate the listbox, you'd have to use `Additem` method . The `Value` method would return the selected value in the listbox by the user not the opposite way. (BTW, why using Listboxes if you have only one value to show ?, use textbox instead)

Third point, for the run time error, it would be better to give a correct debug by showing the line of error. But, I would suggest that you check if the Table is already existing in the worksheet of your data. If it does, then check if its name matches the one you've put in your VBA code (same for column names)

**EDIT :** 
One of the User Friendly solutions can be as follows :

1 - Make your own user form that will have basically 4 Textboxes and a button for searching.

2 - Define your own function that returns the row that contains target data.

3 - Define a sub that takes that input row and uses it to fill the textboxes with the data

The function can for example :

```
Function Row_Of_Data(Asset_Num as String, Serial_Num as String, Search_Table as String) as Long
Dim Target_Data as Range
Dim T_Row as Long
'Now, we set a range that contains all of the data in the table object in your worksheet
On Error Goto Unfound 
Set Target_Data = Sheet2.ListObjects(Search_Table).DataBodyRange
If Asset_Num <> "" AND Serial_Num = ""  Then 
     Row_Of_Data = WorksheetFunction.Match(Asset_Num,Target_Data.Columns(1),False)
Elseif Serial_Num <> "" AND Asset_Num = "" Then
   Row_Of_Data = WorksheetFunction.Match(Asset_Num,Target_Data.Columns(2),False)
Else 
   Row_Of_Data = WorksheetFunction.Match(Asset_Num,Target_Data.Columns(1),False)
End if
Exit Function
Unfound:
Row_Of_Data = 0


End Function
```

Comment: I found a couple websites that suggested using INDEXMATCH is more versatile than VLOOKUP, so I went with it. Also, thanks for pointing out the listbox issue - I noticed that after the fact and changed them to textboxes. Thanks for the advice, I'll try out your suggestions and see what I can come up with.